# URL path string is treated as unsafe character encoding in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am building a project in ReactJS. One of my `Route` path is

`<Route path="/person/profile" element={<PersonProfile />} />`

When I try to link to the page via this route, i.e.,

```
<Link to="/person/profilе">
    <img src={Account} className="icon" alt="" />
</Link>
```

I get an error: `No routes matched location "/person/profil%D0%B5"`.

When I change the URL from `profile` to something else, it works fine. What could be the problem with my code? And why is the letter `e` in the `profile` treated as unsafe?

Comment: Your `Route` has `profile`, ending in "LATIN SMALL LETTER E". Your `Link` has `profilе`, ending in "CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER IE"

Comment: You've simply a typo between the path/target values. Nothing at all to do with character encodings, unsafe or not.